# Code exiting issue in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exit, ros, rospy

I am working on ROS and I have written a code in `Python 2.7` and in the menu I am asking the user to select either option 1 or 2. After the task is accomplished, when I press `Ctrl+c`, instead of exiting the code, it displays the menu again, instead of exiting. Here again if I choose between 1 or 2, it keeps printing the menu again and again.

What changes in the code would be suggested in order to exit the code as soon as I press `Ctrl+c` instead of displaying the menu again and again?

The code and the screen shot of the problem are below:

```
if __name__=='__main__':    
  while(True):  
    try:
        print "***********"
        print "1. Continuous"
        print "2. Single Step"
        print "***********"
        try:
            choice = int(raw_input('Choose a number between 1 & 2: '))
            number = choice
            move_group_python_interface()

        except ValueError:
            print "ERROR! Choose a number between 1 and 2"

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    break
```

[image: **SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR**]

Comment: There are indentation problems in your code. Could you please fix them.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the error message as text.

Comment: Hey, I fixed the indentation problems @Gelineau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was with `while(True):`. Once I comment it out, it exits without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at `move_group_python_interface()` it is very difficult to say.

Examining your error screen shot (in the future, include the error text in the question), you were hitting `^C` as part of the flow when `move_group_python_interface()` was triggered.

If `move_group_python_interface()` entails starting a new process, then you exited that process.

Try hitting `^C` as part of the menu flow. It seems to exit fine for me.

If you are curious about how to capture `^C` and respond accordingly

Check this out

```
if __name__=='__main__':
  while(True):
    try:
        print "***********"
        print "1. Continuous"
        print "2. Single Step"
        print "***********"
        try:
            choice = int(raw_input('Choose a number between 1 & 2: '))
            number = choice
            move_group_python_interface()

        except ValueError:
            print "ERROR! Choose a number between 1 and 2"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Bye bye"
        break
```

when executed prints

```
bash > python infloop.py
***********
1. Continuous
2. Single Step
***********
Choose a number between 1 & 2: ^CBye bye
```

(Sorry but I don't got ROS)